# Using filter_var() to validate integer value greater than or equal to 1

Tags: php, validation, integer, filter-var

im currenly working on a e-book project

Obviously, it makes sense to divide up the e-books into categories rather than lump them together.

while creating an ebook the admin is required to specify a category by keying in the primary key of the category(which is an integer greater than or equal to 1)

one of the ways to validate the category number being keyed in is using the filter_var() function

I have downloaded a sample ebook project from the internet and this is how they are validating the category number(which is is an integer greater than or equal to 1) --------

```
if(filter_var($_POST['category'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)))
```

I'm not able to understand the last argument being passed to the filter_var(). (I have absolutely no doubt about the first two arguments)

Please help me understand.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm not able to understand the last argument being passed to the filter_var().

[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) here filters a `$_POST['category']` with the specified filter [FILTER_VALIDATE_INT](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) that validates value as integer, optionally from the specified range that is defined as method's last argument `array('min_range' => 1)`

Quoting [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

> options - Associative array of options or bitwise disjunction of flags.